# Comparing number sizes for numbers that start with 0?

Tags: php, comparison

I am trying to compare numbers against each other in terms of size and pick the closest (largest) value.

For example i have the array of numbers: 0541, 0555, 0789.

And a number: 0547.

In this case 0555 would be my desired number.

My code works for all numbers not starting with a 0, but with the above example it fails.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Should have made it clear, not all numbers start with a 0, and the number to be compared is the time so is it still possible to remove the zero from that?

Comment: Or compare each digit individually from left to right

Comment: Beware octal numbers! http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski - interesting point, but even octals would end up in the correct order.  I think PHP would make sure two numbers in different bases were converted to a common base before comparing :)

Answer (score 3):

If you have a number that starts with a `0` it will be compared as a string.  Turn the numbers into integers before comparing using `intval` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php)

Comment: won't it be considered as 8-base (Octal) number? So won't 012 = Dec 10? Of course, if they are written without quotes (author did not mention that)

Comment: `intval` is going to convert the number to an integer (base 10) regardless of leading indicators, unless you provide an optional base parameter.